# Where is ConfigurationManager's namespace?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, reference, configurationmanager, system.configuration

I've got a reference to `System.Configuration` - and `ConfigurationSettings` is found no problem - but the type or namespace '`ConfigurationManager`' could not be found!?

I've read around - and it looks like it should belong to the same namespace as the `ConfigurationSettings` class.

EDIT: Please take note - **I've clearly said I have added a reference to System.Configuration**. There's been 4 comments already about this.

Comment: You need to add reference to `System.Configuration`

Comment: Version 3.5. I've added a reference - read the OP.

Comment: Please post the code where you get that warning.  Perhaps it's a syntax problem.  Also look in Object Explorer under System.Configuration to see if ConfigurationManager is there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

ConfigurationManager is a part of the System.Configuration after .Net 2.0. Add a reference to the System.Configuration dll. Try using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use the System Configuration namespace, this must be included in **two ways**:

1. Right click the project and choose add reference, browse "Assemblies" and tick the **System.Configuration** assembly.
2. Include the namespace in code:

   using System.Configuration;

Comment: View the properties of the reference you have added, get the location and try and browse to it.

Comment: using the "using System.Configuration" didn't work for me. However adding via the "right-click > add reference > assemblies > System.Configuration" solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for actually including steps as to how one adds a reference.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference the System.Configuration assembly.  This namespace was split across a few assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add the System.Configuration reference under the Reference folder in your project. Only adding the system.configuration with the using statement in your class is not enough.

Comment: The author stated: `I've clearly said I have added a reference to System.Configuration`. Additionally, this question is more than two years old, please answer a more current question next time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working in VisualStudio 2015, and `ConfigurationManager` is not present at `System.Configuration` namespace anymore.

I was just trying to read the App.config file...

Then I found a solution:

Get:

```
string str = MyProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default["MySettingName"].ToString();
```

Set:

```
MyProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default["MySettingName"]="myString";
MyProjectNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using VS 2017, I added 'using System.Configuration' directive and also follow the step to add a reference assembly to the project but IDE still complaint configuration manager does not exist, it turn out it is due to the .net core installed by Nuget just add a empty container. The package System.Configuration.Configurationmanager 4.5.0 need to be installed as well. 
Start Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console and type "Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0" and this resolve the problem. Refer below screenshot in Object Browser in VS2017

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was solved when I put the "BuildConnectionString" function in a class and added "Imports System.Configuration" at the top of the class page. I did as the Microsoft site itself says.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders

```
Private Sub BuildConnectionString(ByVal dataSource As String, _
ByVal userName As String, ByVal userPassword As String)

' Retrieve the partial connection string named databaseConnection
' from the application's app.config or web.config file.
Dim settings As ConnectionStringSettings = _
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("partialConnectString")

If Not settings Is Nothing Then
    ' Retrieve the partial connection string.
    Dim connectString As String = settings.ConnectionString
    Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", connectString)

    ' Create a new SqlConnectionStringBuilder based on the
    ' partial connection string retrieved from the config file.
    Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString)

    ' Supply the additional values.
    builder.DataSource = dataSource
    builder.UserID = userName
    builder.Password = userPassword

    Console.WriteLine("Modified: {0}", builder.ConnectionString)
End If
End Sub
```

The important point is to use the function in the class. When I did this the error failed to find the source.

Answer (score 0):

Summer 2021, Visual Studio 2019 (core application). I had copied in some code with

```
ConfigurationManager.AppeSettings["yadayada"];
```

Just click the light bulb icon on the line where the problem appear and choose to instal System.Configuration Package.